# ng-repeat animation not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My animation with ng-repeat does not seem to work . Here is the plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/kYtzM9d0rzGmrniybz9c?p=preview

Any inputs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1.** You have registered two modules:

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
```

And:

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
```

Remove `ng-app` from the html tag.

**2.** You need to load `angular-animate.js`

**3.** As you are moving the elements within the array, it's neither `enter` or `leave` you should use, but instead `move`: `.ng-move {`

**4.** You are using the `ng-animate` directive (`ng-animate="'animate'"`) which is deprecated since 1.2. You are also passing it a class that does not exist.

This would work:

```
.ng-move {
  transition: 1.75s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.ng-move.ng-move-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

But I would recommend giving it a specific class to be able to specify which ng-repeat uses which animation:

```
.move-animation.ng-move {
  transition: 1.75s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.move-animation.ng-move.ng-move-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And:

```
<td class="move-animation" ng-repeat="cust in customers" ng-click="swap(this.$index)">
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/fiMORm5ZFLejV1aOUrbR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and pointing out the bugs , it makes it easier to understand and learn