# Can't get animation with ng-repeat working

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

I have a simple ng-repeat with animate. I already made my module to depend on ngAnimate, and I already defined my transitions in CSS using classes like `.ng-enter` and `.ng-enter-active`.

I went to the related post like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580599/how-to-use-animation-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465253/ng-repeat-animation-not-working) but I can't get my code to work. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsutandi/Lfmp8pdu/3/) of it. I find that the reason is my item doesn't get `.ng-enter` class assigned to it, but I am not sure why I can't do it this way. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi blenzcoffee, what animation are you expecting? Sliding to the left?

As far as I can see, it looks like you are replacing content, and the classes you're animating are never applied to the elements when clicking next/prev. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JannikRasmussen yes. It should change to left:500px. But currently, it doesn't do any animation (I think it's because my item doesn't get ng-enter class assigned to it)

Comment: @JannikRasmussen Yes, I just updated my question right before I made the comment.. I think the problem is I am replacing the content and that's the reason why ng-enter never gets applied. So, in other words I cannot do it this way? I am trying to achieve 'carousel' effect

Comment: Is it acceptable that your container has a fixed width?

You can have a carousel effect, but you have to let the animation happen first - and then replace conent. Or rather replace the first/last div after animation with whatever is next in line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved, but not with how you're filtering the data. Instead of your current filter actually updating and the `ng-repeat` rendering new elements, you're just simply changing the data, which doesn't re-render and no animate classes are applied. But, if change how you're filter so that it actually uses the filter, then things start working.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfmp8pdu/4/

```
angular
.module('App', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller('AppCtrl', [
  function() {
    var data = this;
    data.next = next;
    data.previous = previous;

    init();

    function init() {
      data.items = [
        {title: "One", page: 1},
        {title: "Two", page: 1},
        {title: "Three", page: 1},
        {title: "Four", page: 2},
        {title: "Five", page: 2},
        {title: "Six", page: 2},
        {title: "Seven", page: 3}
      ];

      data.page = 1;
    }

    function next() {
      data.page++;
    }

    function previous() {
      data.page--;
    }
  }
]);
```

And the modified filter in html:

```
<div class="itemsContainer">
  <span ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter:ctrl.page" class="animate">
    {{item.title}}
  </span>
</div>
```

This is not a good way to do this as far as the pagination goes. There are better solutions out there. Also, if you want this to be more like a true carousel, then you could try just inlining all of your elements and shifting the entire thing left/right - so in that case, everything would always be rendered, you would not use a filter, but instead change the left/right absolute position in CSS via your buttons.

Comment: Hi, isn't filtering stuff is better? That way we don't need to render everything in case we have a lot of items (1000 for example), so technically it's better for performance?

Comment: In that case, yes. I wasn't sure what you were trying to accomplish.